# Export a Excel-Table in a Powerpoint Template

Tags: python, excel, pandas, powerpoint

I have a dataframe (Excel-table) and want to export this table in a powerpoint template. Is this possible with python or do I have to use macros for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `dataframe` I guess that you are using pandas to read some excel file?

There is the [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module, which can create and update powerpoint files, so yes it should be possible.